# Two PCs, one ethernet port - whats the best solution

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have two PCs which need to share one ethernet port.

What is the best solution?

I have tried using a splitter, and then two splitters.....only one PC gets internet at a time.

What can I try?

Thanks

Comment: Do you by chance have access to both ends of the ethernet port? If so, there's a possibility.

Comment: True. But only up to 100mbit. (gbit uses all 8 cables).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use a ethernet splitter to connect a router to two devices?](http://superuser.com/questions/814364/can-i-use-a-ethernet-splitter-to-connect-a-router-to-two-devices), [Difference between Ethernet splitter and switch](http://superuser.com/questions/104050/difference-between-ethernet-splitter-and-switch)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommended purchasing a network switch (not a hub!).

[Here is a useful link](https://www.udemy.com/blog/hub-vs-switch/) explaining the differences between a Hub and a Switch

Comment: Something like this would suffice - http://www.amazon.com/TP-LINK-TL-SF1005D-5-port-100Mbps-Desktop/dp/B000FNFSPY/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1414752526&sr=8-1&keywords=Switch

Comment: I agree with you on getting a switch rather than a hub, but I disagree with your choice in switch. Getting a gigabit switch isn't much more expensive, and as long as the rest of your network is gigabit, you'll get much better speeds. Go with something like this: http://www.amazon.com/D-Link-5-Port-Gigabit-Desktop-GO-SW-5G/dp/B008BGXZUC/

Comment: @Adam - good shout, I would agree. If you was just sharing say a 10MB internet connection (no file or print sharing) then just go with a cheap switch. But if you want the higher speed, and you have the money then a GB switch is worth the investment

Answer (score 1):

If this "one" ethernet port is your WAN or the one coming out of your modem, and it doesn't have a built in router, or your modem only provides one WAN address, then it would make more sense to get a router instead of a switch. A router can hand out dhcp address's to your two client computers and provide security. If this is your scenario, I think it would be safer to get a router rather than buying a switch, just to find out you need a router.

Comment: Good Shout - I did not consider this!

Answer (score 0):

Use a hub. Hubs are designed for this explicitely (to "share" an ethernet port).

Comment: Goo dluck finding a hub.  Switches are now as cheap at hubs were and are better in almost all cases. I know of no store which still sells 10mbit or 100mbit hubs. Just 100mb or 1Gb switches.

Answer (score 0):

> I have two PCs which need to share one Ethernet port.
>   What is the best solution?

if both need to be on at the same time or if you do not want to continuously plug in and remove cables: Get a switch with at least 3 ports.  One to connect to the current cable. Two to connect to your PCs.

Note that 3 port switches are rare. Most models start with 4 ports, which will give you a spare on for the future (e.g. if you ever want to add a printer, or connect a laptop, ...)

> I have tried using a splitter, and then two splitters.....only one PC gets internet
>   at a time.

Splitters will not work. There are several posts on this site already explaining why.

> What can I try?

You can:

- Get switch
- Or connect the Ethernet cable to a PC with atleast two NICs and that that PC forward data.

```
     Wall socket# ----  #PC1# -----#PC2
```

Where the --- are Ethernet cables and the #'s aqre network cards.
Note that to use the network from PC2 you will need to have PC1 powered up and properly configured.

Usually it is much less hassle to just buy a cheap switch.